# Callback to manipulate photo before it is saved to file

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-camera

I'd like to take photo and compress its size before saving it to file.
According to what I understand from android developer guide, I can only save the photo to file first and then compress it.

```
File photoFile = //aquire file path to the saved photo...
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
...
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.i("addNewActivity","onActivityResult");
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
          //...compress the photo and re-save it again to the file.
        }
    }
```

Is it the best practice for this flow? Can't I get in callback the byte[] of the image and manipulate it **before** it is being saved to file?

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PictureCallback.html

Comment: saw this suggested page. It has a notification: "This interface was deprecated in API level 21.
We recommend using the new android.hardware.camera2 API for new applications."

Comment: yes that is deprecated and you need to use the latest api android.hardware.camera. There are callbacks that you need to use

Comment: you can look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PictureCallback.html

Comment: Which callback and how to use them? Is it 'onCaptureProgressed'? is it called before the photo is saved to file? I am looking for an example (if someone already dealt with this situation)

Comment: you can look at the examples in the sdk . another link that might help http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback

Comment: "I'd like to take photo and compress its size before saving it to file" -- usually the photo is already compressed in JPEG format, when the third-party app takes the picture, let alone by the time it writes the picture to disk.

Comment: Commonware, the photos are saved to the disk with more the 1MB per photo. I want to reduce it to a few hundereds KB each.